# How to rename table variables in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, cell-array, axis-labels

I would like to create a table from a matrix of spectra data, using a specific list of variables (column, which here correspond to 1000 spectral wavelenght values) instead of putting the name manually. 
To do so, i use the `array2table` function, and matlab documentation shows that names for rows and label of variables must be put as cell arrays, (and not matrix). So I need to first convert my x-axis (spectral wavelenght) to a cell array. I use the following:

`C = num2cell(xaxis);`  % to convert into a cell array (each cell contain 1 value)

`isvarname C`           % to check that the variable is valid as a cell array

`T = array2table(R,'RowNames', concentration,'VariableNames',C);`

Here: R is the matrix, concentration is a Cell array 1x500, xaxis is the wavelenght of spectral data 1x1000 (which is ranged from 600 to 1800, approx. there is no null value).

Unfortunately, I got the following error: 
"Error using array2table (line 62)
The VariableNames property must be a cell array, with each element containing one nonempty string."

which means I can input properly the columns (variable) names (while row names, however, works fine). 
Note: i tried the 
`T.Properties.VariableNames = c` but it is not working either.

I checked the other post on table name value but its not helping,
Any thought about this? 
Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/modify-units-descriptions-and-table-variable-names.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you mistyped your question's code, but it seems that you are using the array `xaxis` instead of `C`. Anyway, I suggest you try casting the cells content to strings this way

```
T = array2table(R,'RowNames', concentration,'VariableNames',cellfun(@(x)num2str(x),num2cell(xaxis),'uniformoutput',false));
```

---

### Edit

Looking through the [table docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html)  it says that

> Variable names, specified as the comma-separated pair consisting of 'VariableNames' and a cell array of character vectors that are nonempty and distinct. The number of character vectors must equal the number of variables. The variable names that you assign must be valid MATLAB® variable names. You can determine valid variable names using the function isvarname.

Furthermore, the [isvarname](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isvarname.html) function says that

> A valid variable name begins with a letter and contains not more than `namelengthmax` characters. Valid variable names can include letters, digits, and underscores. MATLAB keywords are not valid variable names. To determine if the input is a MATLAB keyword, use the `iskeyword` function.

This means that you cannot use the `xaxis` values as variable names by themselves, you need to, at least, prepend a character and remove the decimal dot. You can do so with the following

```
T = array2table(R,'RowNames', concentration,...
    'VariableNames',cellfun(@(x)['wavel_',regexprep(num2str(x),'.','_')],num2cell(xaxis),'uniformoutput',false));
```

This code will prepend 'wavel_' to the numerical string value. It will also replace the dots with underscores using the `regexprep` function. However, it seems like this is really unnecessary because the column names are not really informative. The `array2table` function's doc says that if you don't supply the `'variableNames'` option it will do the following:

> If valid MATLAB identifiers are not available for use as variable names, MATLAB uses a cell array of N character vectors of the form {'Var1' ... 'VarN'} where N is the number of variables.

Maybe using the default variable names is good enough.

Comment: Looks good, however as xaxis is made of number, I got the following error:'600.669' is not a valid variable name.

Comment: If you really want to use the numbers as variable names, you could use a `regexprep` to replace the dots with underscores. I'll check if those are allowed

Comment: The docs are a bit sketchy but say that the variablenames must be strings that can be valid workspace variable names. That means that any symbol except the underscore is disallowed. Only ascii letters, numbers and the underscore can be in the name.

Comment: Dear Lucianopaz, thank you very much for your valuable input, however when I use only the first 3 digits of the xaxis (600, 602, ... 1800) it does not work. number only are maybe not allowed?

Comment: Your right, numbers only are not alliwed. Variable names must start with a letter

Comment: Well this s^^^. Thank you very much for your answers Lucianopaz ! I voted your answer although my count is not visible. Regarding my table-related issue, I also thought about using a time-series instead, as the wavelength axis of spectral data is not linear and should be plotted as a time serie, however matlab oblige you, again, to put a certain input format as date... its gonna be a long newyear^^

Comment: @arno, I know that MATLAB has its limitations to naming variables in a table, but I think that my answer points them out and suggest how to work around them. What else would it take for you to accept my answer as correct?